# Add and substract a subtitle using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to convert a mkv file to a mp4 file. In the mkv file there is a subtitle I don’t want. However, there is another subtitle I want to add.

The streams are as follow:

- 0:0 video
- 0:1 audio
- 0:2 subtitle

Input #1 anothersubtitle.srt*

The command I give is as follow:

`ffmpeg -i video.mkv -i anothersubtitle.srt -map 0:v -c:v copy -map 0:a -c:a:0 aac -ab:a:0 256k -ar:a:0 48000 -ac:a:0 2 -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -metadata:s:a:0 title=Stereo -map 1 -map -0:s output.mp4`

Ffmpeg gives an error:

`Automatic encoder selection failed for output stream #0:2. Default encoder for format ipod (codec none) is probably disabled. Please choose an encoder manually.
Error selecting an encoder for stream 0:2`

The error it comes up with is about the stream with the subtitle I don’t want. Adding “*-c:s mov_text*” or “*-scodec mov_text*” will still select the unwanted subtitle. This will add the subtitle I want, but it also adds the subtitle I don’t want.

On this and other sites there are numerous examples to be found to add or subtract a wanted or unwanted stream, but i could not find a way where i can leave one subtitle out and add another one. Can you help me out?

**Edit (adding full console output as requested):**

```
ffmpeg version 3.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'movie.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libebml v1.0.0 + libmatroska v1.0
  Duration: 03:15:12.66, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 9616 kb/s
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 203.161000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:00:00.000
    Chapter #0:1: start 203.161000, end 612.153000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:03:23.161
    Chapter #0:2: start 612.153000, end 891.307000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:10:12.153
    Chapter #0:3: start 891.307000, end 1048.714000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:14:51.307
    Chapter #0:4: start 1048.714000, end 1302.384000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:17:28.714
    Chapter #0:5: start 1302.384000, end 1428.010000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:21:42.384
    Chapter #0:6: start 1428.010000, end 1837.669000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:23:48.010
    Chapter #0:7: start 1837.669000, end 2063.728000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:30:37.669
    Chapter #0:8: start 2063.728000, end 2503.751000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:34:23.728
    Chapter #0:9: start 2503.751000, end 2656.737000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:41:43.751
    Chapter #0:10: start 2656.737000, end 3055.761000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:44:16.737
    Chapter #0:11: start 3055.761000, end 3309.431000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:50:55.761
    Chapter #0:12: start 3309.431000, end 3404.860000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:55:09.431
    Chapter #0:13: start 3404.860000, end 4424.754000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:56:44.860
    Chapter #0:14: start 4424.754000, end 4625.704000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:13:44.754
    Chapter #0:15: start 4625.704000, end 5162.115000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:17:05.704
    Chapter #0:16: start 5162.115000, end 5366.319000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:26:02.115
    Chapter #0:17: start 5366.319000, end 5521.182000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:29:26.319
    Chapter #0:18: start 5521.182000, end 5916.869000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:32:01.182
    Chapter #0:19: start 5916.869000, end 6199.777000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:38:36.869
    Chapter #0:20: start 6199.777000, end 6576.612000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:43:19.777
    Chapter #0:21: start 6576.612000, end 6945.981000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:49:36.612
    Chapter #0:22: start 6945.981000, end 7122.824000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:55:45.981
    Chapter #0:23: start 7122.824000, end 7379.789000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:58:42.824
    Chapter #0:24: start 7379.789000, end 7609.310000
    Metadata:
      title           : 02:02:59.789
    Chapter #0:25: start 7609.310000, end 7811.637000
    Metadata:
      title           : 02:06:49.310
    Chapter #0:26: start 7811.637000, end 8024.725000
    Metadata:
      title           : 02:10:11.637
    Chapter #0:27: start 8024.725000, end 8301.376000
    Metadata:
      title           : 02:13:44.725
    Chapter #0:28: start 8301.376000, end 8806.506000
    Metadata:
      title           : 02:18:21.376
    Chapter #0:29: start 8806.506000, end 9255.621000
    Metadata:
      title           : 02:26:46.506
    Chapter #0:30: start 9255.621000, end 9528.018000
    Metadata:
      title           : 02:34:15.621
    Chapter #0:31: start 9528.018000, end 9675.416000
    Metadata:
      title           : 02:38:48.018
    Chapter #0:32: start 9675.416000, end 9981.763000
    Metadata:
      title           : 02:41:15.416
    Chapter #0:33: start 9981.763000, end 10092.332000
    Metadata:
      title           : 02:46:21.763
    Chapter #0:34: start 10092.332000, end 10223.171000
    Metadata:
      title           : 02:48:12.332
    Chapter #0:35: start 10223.171000, end 10528.393000
    Metadata:
      title           : 02:50:23.171
    Chapter #0:36: start 10528.393000, end 10911.359000
    Metadata:
      title           : 02:55:28.393
    Chapter #0:37: start 10911.359000, end 11106.721000
    Metadata:
      title           : 03:01:51.359
    Chapter #0:38: start 11106.721000, end 11331.278000
    Metadata:
      title           : 03:05:06.721
    Chapter #0:39: start 11331.278000, end 11712.659000
    Metadata:
      title           : 03:08:51.278
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1040, SAR 1:1 DAR 24:13, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: dts (DTS), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : DTS
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: subrip
    Metadata:
      title           : English
Input #1, srt, from 'anothersubtitle.srt':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Subtitle: subrip
Automatic encoder selection failed for output stream #0:2. Default encoder for format mp4 (codec none) is probably disabled. Please choose an encoder manually.
Error selecting an encoder for stream 0:2
```

Comment: Show the full console output.

Comment: added as requested.